# WCF Router that combines / aggregates many underlying service responses

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-configuration, wcf-routing

I have a WCF Routing service with two underlying services. The thing I want to get working is combining responses from two backend services and returning one aggregated response (which consists of each of two services are called by router).

Each of that two services returns array of strings. For instance, if the first service returns `new string[2] { "red", "green" }` and the second's result is  `new string[2] { "table", "chair" }`, the whole final response that will go from router back to client is `new string[4] { "red", "green", "table", "chair" }`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something from your question, is the following the sort of thing you are looking for?

Assuming a WCF service method called GetAggregatedResponse:

```
public string[] GetAggregatedResponse()
{
    string[] service1Response = callService1AndGetResult();
    string[] service2Response = callService2AndGetResult();
    string[] aggregatedResponse = service1Response.Concat(service2Response).ToArray();
    // Or if you would like to remove duplicates from the results:
    // string[] aggregatedResponse = service1Response.Union(service2Response).ToArray();
    return aggregatedResponse;
}
```

Comment: It is exactly the sort of thing I want to do. Moreover, I would do it that way if there is no WCF Routing Service. The deal is to force WCF Routing service summarize / aggregate / combine such two requests. It is because I have two WCF services and router as a frontend. If there are any misunderstandings so please let me know.

Comment: I don't really understand. If your WCF routing service is 'client facing' can't that just call the other services within it's implementation then combine the results as above?

Comment: The thing that there is no `WCF Routing service implementation`. It is new feature in WCF 4.0. The class `System.ServiceModel.Routing.RoutingService` is responsible for that purpose,

Comment: I don't think you can use the built in RoutingService to do this. From the documentation:  "The channel shape must not be request-reply because only one reply can be received by the client application in response to the request." I think to include this kind of logic you will need to write your own 'routing' WCF service which manually calls your underlying services.